# Haunt #22 room choice

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

In Haunt #22, *The Abyss Gazes Back*, the house is collapsing into The Abyss.

The traitor is sometimes allowed to choose the next room which will collapse into the abyss. One of the ways they can do this is with the following rule from the Traitor's Tome:

> If the Abyss engulfs a whole floor, it moves to the next floor up, starting in an unoccupied room of your choosing with an unexplored door.

If there is no such room available, which room should be collapsed by the traitor?

Comment: The second question seems obvious, they have to do two more rooms, so that they collapse three in total (last room in floor A, chosen room in floor B, next room in f C).

Comment: So the traitor's collapsed room *does* count towards the hero's total collapse value? The rules don't specify this either way.

Comment: The traitor does not collapse the first room of the next floor directly;  choose *which* room to collapse *if* one is supposed to.

Comment: This is two questions.  They should be posted separately.

Comment: Edit: reduced to a single question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good news is that it's [impossible for a floor to lack an available door](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/29117/3212). The bad news is that it's quite possible for the Heroes to be standing in all of the rooms of a floor that have an available door.

This is a hole in the [rules](http://media.wizards.com/2015/rules/betrayal_rules.pdf), and there is no rules-strict way to solve this. I can suggest a few alternatives, with my favorites first:

1. Allow the Traitor to select any room on the *outside* of a floor (i.e., pretend that all of the rooms have doors in every direction for the purposes of selecting this room).
2. Allow the traitor to select a room with a "false door", that doesn't go through to another room because the other room doesn't have a door. (This will be a room in the middle of the floor somewhere.)
3. Fall back to the "floor has been sealed" rules, and permit the current player to rearrange the floor to produce a room with an available door that does not contain a Hero. Note that *who* gets to rearrange the floor is going to drastically affect who wins, and it's currently the Traitor's turn.
4. Allow the Traitor to select *any* room on the floor.